# How do I display the output of a countdown timer script in HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, countdown

I am trying to figure out how to display the output of this timer script I found online within another script. Here is the timer script I found:

```js
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();
    
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
    
      // Get today's date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();
    
      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
      // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
      // If the count down is finished, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
```

```html
    <!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to be able to display the timer where I put "I want to display the timer here".

```
  <div class="flash-infos">   
    <div class="flash-info">
      <font color="white"; font size = 2; ><b>"I want to display the timer here"</b></font> <center>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to use the command `document.getElementById("demo")`?
In fact the description told you how to use it.

Comment: @KNVB, I did that but nothing appeared I used   <div class="flash-infos">   
    <div class="flash-info">
      <font color="white"; font size = 2; ><b>id="demo"</b></font> <center>
    </div>    
  </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I am assuming that you are using id="demo" in your "p" tag as well as "font" tag. So the former takes precedence. Just keep id="demo" here:

```
 <div class="flash-infos">   
    <div class="flash-info">
      <font font size = 2; ><b id="demo"></b></font> <center>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

And remove any other id="demo" that you have used in other parts of HTML. Notice I have removed color="white", not sure if it syncs with the default background color. Try setting a different color if white may be the case.

Comment: That worked! Removing the other id = "demo" solved the problem!! I still have the color = "white" in mine. @Deepak

Comment: Is there a way I can also add text to the left of the count down timer?

Comment: Definitely there is. Use your script like: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your content here... " +  days + "d " + hours + "h "

Comment: That worked as well thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
<b id="memo"></b>
```

Comment: I tried that as well, so my bar cycles through various text I put in and when it gets to the scripts for id="demo" nothing appears. I put the font color as white so it should display something. Should I be putting the script below where I am trying to display the text? @The KNVB. Where I am trying to place the id=demo is also in a script

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: My solution is same as the `Deepak`.

Comment: It is the difference was I still had the 2 id = "demo" in yours. But essentially the same